# Moving average from incoming serial data C#/.NET

Tags: c#, .net, arduino

I have a program which reads analog data from an Arduino UNO R3 and sends that data along to other equipment which reads it and performs some actions accordingly. At the moment, every time I read data, it is being sent along, which is creating way more datapoints than needed to perform the task. Therefore, I would like to lump together the data in a moving average which is sent along instead. My code looks like this at the moment:

```cs
string forceAnalog = recieveData.Text;
recieveData.Clear();
var forceList = forceAnalog.ToUpper().Split(':').ToList();
foreach (var item in forceList)
    if (item.Trim().StartsWith("X"))
    {
        textBoxX.Text = item.Remove(0, 1);
    }
    else if (item.Trim().StartsWith("Y"))
    {
        textBoxY.Text = item.Remove(0, 1);
    }
    else if (item.Trim().StartsWith("Z"))
    {
        textBoxZ.Text = item.Remove(0, 1);
    }

string forceXanalog = textBoxX.Text;
string forceYanalog = textBoxY.Text;
string forceZanalog = textBoxZ.Text;

if (double.TryParse(forceXanalog, out forceX)) ;
if (double.TryParse(forceYanalog, out forceY)) ;
if (double.TryParse(forceZanalog, out forceZ)) ;

forceXvalue = (forceX * calibrationFactorX / 1023) - 5;
forceYvalue = (forceY * calibrationFactorY / 1023) - 5;
forceZvalue = (forceZ * calibrationFactorZ / 1023) - 50;

this.forceXlabel.Text = string.Format("{0:F2}", forceXvalue);
this.forceYlabel.Text = string.Format("{0:F2}", forceYvalue);
this.forceZlabel.Text = string.Format("{0:F2}", forceZvalue);
```

I read the data from a textBox which receives the Arduino serial stream, and create the forceAnalog string from it. The string contains X,Y,Z values and looks something like: X-0.44 Y-0.15 Z-0.5 then receiveData is being cleared and reads the values again. This is then sent through a few calculations and to labels.

What I want to to is, instead of reading, storing one set of X,Y,Z values and passing it along, I would like to read for example 5,10,100... sets of X,Y,Z values, then create an average from these and pass it along for calculations. How do I go about doing this?

Comment: Do you want a moving average or you want average of every n values? I mean if n = 2 and you have 1, 2, 3, 4 do you want [1, 1.5, 2.5, 3.5] or you want [1.5, 3.5]?

Comment: You'll have to somehow store the last 5, 10, 100 or how many sets of X, Y and Z values, I recommend some sort of circular buffer (there is no built in circular buffer, you'll have to write your own or use a [opensource implementation](https://github.com/joaoportela/CircularBuffer-CSharp)), then it's trivially easy to calculate an average of those measuremeants

Comment: @Emad in this case if I have n = 3 sets of numbers which are ([XYZ]) [1 1 3], [2 3 4], [3 2 2], I want to produce [2 2 3], then send this on for calculations.

Comment: @MindSwipe thank you, circular buffer meaning that if I want to calculate the average of 100 sets of values, I will buffer 100 sets of values, calculate the average, clear and then store another 100 sets?

Comment: @MindSwipe I am very new to C#, I have added the CircularBuffer.cs file to my project, but I can't figure out how to actually use it. Any advice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest option would be to accumulate n number of items, send the average, and reset the accumulator and count. Using an iterator block and system.Numerics for Vector3:

```
public static IEnumerable<Vector3> AverageN(
    this IEnumerable<Vector3> highFrequencySamples,
    int everNthSample)
{
    var acc = Vector3.Zero;
    var n = 0;
    foreach (var sample in highFrequencySamples)
    {
        acc += sample;
        n++;
        if (n == everNthSample)
        {
            // Output the average since we have reached the number of samples needed
            yield return acc / n;
            acc = Vector3.Zero;
            n = 0;
        }
    }

    if (n > 0)
    {
        yield return acc / n;
    }
}
```

While Vector3 this is limited to floats, creating a equivalent `Vector3d` using doubles should be fairly simple. Using a dedicated type for bundling the coordinate values tend to make your code much simpler, since you do not have to repeat each operation three times. If they manage to ship something like [generic math](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/preview-features-in-net-6-generic-math/) you could make a method like this generic, and applicable to all types that support addition and division.

Comment: many thanks you for your answer, it is exactly what I want to do. Being very new to C# I have a few questions or clarifications needed:

First, should I create a vector named highFrequencySamples and pass it into the function, or should I just pass the serial stream without storing any values? Not sure about the mechanics.

Second, I am trying to call the function but not managing. This is what I did:

AverageN(forceAnalogFloat,10)

And the error message I got was: 

Argument 1: cannot convert from 'float' to 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<System.Numberics.Vector3>

Comment: @AlexanderEngman in this example `highFrequencySamples` would be a sequence of vector3 . `IEnumerable` is a type of iterator, i.e. a sequence of values. How exactly you get values and how to send is not shown in your example, so if you want to wrap them in a `IEnumerable`, or extract the relevant parts of the code is up to you